# Tracking Extracts not available under the Data Extracts activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, data-extract, tracking-extract

As the title explains, in *Automation Studio*, when I create a new *Data Extract* activity I do not see the option to set it to "Tracking Extract". [According to the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_tracking_extract_config.htm&type=5), I should be able to see the option in the drop-down.

> Create a data extract activity in Marketing Cloud Automation Studio by
>   selecting Tracking Extract from the Extract Type drop-down. Configure
>   the tracking extract fields to specify the data you want to include.
>   Once configured, start your activity to produce results.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained further in documentation, under [Extract Output Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_extract_types_reference.htm&type=5).

> Extract types must be provisioned for your account. Contact your
>   Marketing Cloud representative for more information.

Just log a new support case requesting these to be enabled on your MC instance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's what I did.